# Rails undefined method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, null

I can't figure out for the life of me why is this crashing.  I have read tons of guides on stackoverflow and google searches and they all say the same thing which is what I am doing.

Here is the code:

```
current_schedule_record['next_oil_change'] = Maintenance.where("vehicle_id = ? AND maintenance_type = ?", id, 'oil change').select("kilometres").order('kilometres DESC').first.kilometres
if current_schedule_record['next_oil_change'].blank?
    current_schedule_record['next_oil_change'] = current_schedule_record['next_oil_change']
else
    current_schedule_record['next_oil_change'] = nil
end
```

Basically I am trying to check if that record exists and spit it back out, if it does not return a nil.

Error I get is: `undefined method 'kilometres' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: It is throwing that error because the query you are doing is returning no results. The query itself should be valid.

You should check that there is a record that you are looking for in the database. 

A better way is to check if the result of your query is nil before accessing its attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a small re-factor:

```
maintenance = Maintenance.where("vehicle_id = ? AND maintenance_type = ?", id, 'oil change').select("kilometres").order('kilometres DESC').first

current_schedule_record['next_oil_change'] = maintenance.nil? ? nil : maintenance.kilometres

if current_schedule_record['next_oil_change'].blank?
  current_schedule_record['next_oil_change'] = current_schedule_record['next_oil_change']
else
  current_schedule_record['next_oil_change'] = nil
end
```

*EDIT:*

You were doing nothing wrong, your Maintenance query is not returning any results which would be automatically instantiated as the first maintenance object returned (`.first`).

Since there are no results, then the `.kilometres` method will fail as it is being executed against a `nil` object.

You need to explicitly check if there is an object returned and then execute the `.kilometres` method.

Another option is the `try` method:

```
current_schedule_record['next_oil_change'] = Maintenance.where("vehicle_id = ? AND maintenance_type = ?", id, 'oil change').select("kilometres").order('kilometres DESC').first.try(:kilometres)

if current_schedule_record['next_oil_change'].blank? # Might want a .nil? check here instead.
  current_schedule_record['next_oil_change'] = current_schedule_record['next_oil_change']
else
  current_schedule_record['next_oil_change'] = nil
end
```

Comment: Well for now I used a count check, count number of records, if greater than 0 then perform my select and that works.  But I wanted to figure out what I was doing wrong before so that I know for future projects.  Thanks for trying to help.